Problem with multiple alignments in equation
As you can see in this equation there is multiple alignment:

Why is my code not working:
$$
\begin{aligned}
|A| &= | A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \ldots \cup A_r | \\
   &= \textstyle\sum\limits_{1 \leq i \leq r}\left|A_i\right| &&- \textstyle\sum\limits_{1 \leq i_1<i_2 \leq r}\left|A_{i_1} \cap A_{i_2}\right| \\
   &&+ \textstyle\sum\limits_{1 \leq i_1<i_2<i_3 \leq r}\left|A_{i_1} \cap A_{i_2} \cap A_{i_3}\right| \\
   &&- \ldots + (-1)^{r-1}\left|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \ldots \cap A_r\right| .
\end{aligned}
$$



Although you have already 3 excellent answers, let me just point you out that the fist reason your code is not working is that you're missing one alignment character & in each of the two last lines, to align with the = sign. But that wouldn't be enough to make it right, anyway...

Some notes:

Do not use double $$ for display equation in LaTeX.
\ldots should be \cdots.

You can use align* together with aligned to achieve multiple alignments:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
|A| & = | A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \cdots \cup A_r | \\
    & = \textstyle\sum\limits_{1 \leq i \leq r}\left|A_i\right|
        \begin{aligned}[t]
          & - \textstyle\sum\limits_{1 \leq i_1<i_2 \leq r}\left|A_{i_1} \cap A_{i_2}\right| \\
          & + \textstyle\sum\limits_{1 \leq i_1<i_2<i_3 \leq r}\left|A_{i_1} \cap A_{i_2} \cap A_{i_3}\right| \\
          & - \cdots + (-1)^{r-1}\left|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \cdots \cap A_r\right|.
        \end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\end{document}



Thanks! Do you know why there is a little spacing between |A| and "=" and the rest?

Do you need more space?@calculatormathematical

I am just wondering why there is so much space in the original picture between the = sign.

Maybe the author used some horizontal space commands like \,, \;, \:.


$$ should never be used in a LaTeX document environment.

\ldots should be \dots; in certain circumstances you have to help amsmath and type \dotsb or \dotsc or \dotsm, when the dots are trailing and so you need to specify what would go next (based on the symbol that precedes the trailing dots).

\textstyle\sum\limits is not the best, because it will make everything that follows (on the same line of the display) \textstyle, with different positioning of subscript and superscripts.

All your \left| and \right| commands just add unwanted horizontal spaces; better using \lvert and \rvert.


This said, you can nest aligned, with top-alignment:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\tsum}{\mathop{\textstyle\sum}\displaylimits}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{aligned}
|A| &= | A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \dots \cup A_r | \\[1ex]
    &= \begin{aligned}[t]
       \tsum_{1 \leq i \leq r}\lvert A_i\rvert 
         &- \tsum_{1 \leq i_1<i_2 \leq r} \lvert A_{i_1} \cap A_{i_2}\rvert \\
         &+ \tsum_{1 \leq i_1<i_2<i_3 \leq r}\lvert A_{i_1} \cap A_{i_2} \cap A_{i_3}\rvert \\
         &- \dots + (-1)^{r-1}\lvert A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \dots \cap A_r\rvert .
       \end{aligned}
\end{aligned}
\]

\[
\begin{aligned}
|A| &= | A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \dots \cup A_r | \\[1ex]
    &= \begin{aligned}[t]
       \sum_{1 \leq i \leq r}\lvert A_i\rvert 
         &- \sum_{1 \leq i_1<i_2 \leq r} \lvert A_{i_1} \cap A_{i_2}\rvert \\
         &+ \sum_{1 \leq i_1<i_2<i_3 \leq r}\lvert A_{i_1} \cap A_{i_2} \cap A_{i_3}\rvert \\
         &- \dots + (-1)^{r-1}\lvert A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \dots \cap A_r\rvert .
       \end{aligned}
\end{aligned}
\]

\end{document}

I'd add some vertical space after the first row to help in showing that the next lines are to be considered together. I also add the same with \sum.


Some comments, in no particular order:

Use \dots rather than \ldots, and let the amsmath package determine when to use \ldots and when to use \cdots. (For the example at hand, \cdots will be chosen.)

I suggest you load the mathtools package -- a superset of the amsmath package -- and use its \DeclarePairedDelimiter macro to create a macro called \abs (as well as a companion macro called \abs*, which auto-sizes the vertical bars).

I find \le and \ge easier to write (and on the eye...) than \leq and \geq. Your mileage may vary. :-)



\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\DeclarePairedDelimiter' macro
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\newcommand\tsum[1]{{\textstyle\sum\limits_{#1}}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\abs{A} 
    &= \abs{A_1\cup A_2\cup \dots\cup A_r} \\[1ex]
    &= \tsum{1 \leq i \leq r} \abs{A_i}
       \begin{aligned}[t]
       &- \tsum{1 \le i_1<i_2 \le r} \abs{A_{i_1}\cap A_{i_2}} \\
       &+ \tsum{1 \le i_1<i_2<i_3 \le r} \abs{A_{i_1}\cap A_{i_2}\cap A_{i_3}} \\
       &- \dots + (-1)^{r-1} \abs{A_1\cap A_2\cap \dots\cap A_r}.
       \end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\end{document}

